# Binomial theorem / Generating function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I had trouble figuring out if the following equality holds by applying the binomial theorem and using generating functions. Could anyone please shed some light? Any help is greatly appreciated.

$${n \choose k} = \sum_{x = 0}^{3k} \sum_{y=0}^{x} (-1)^{x} {n \choose {3k-x}} {n \choose y} {y  \choose {x -y}} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another variation of the theme using Egorychevs *formal residual calculus for power series*.

*Note:* This powerful technique is based upon [Cauchys residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and was introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* ([Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://www.amazon.de/Representation-Computation-Combinatorial-Translations-Mathematical/dp/0821845128)) to compute binomial identies.

We use only two aspects of this theory:

> Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j$ be a *formal power series*, then
>
> - Write the binomial coeffients as *residuals* of corresponding *formal power series*
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathop{res}_{z}\frac{A(z)}{z^{j+1}}=a_j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> - Apply the *substitution rule* for formal power series:
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{A(w)}{w^{j+1}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We observe:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x=0}^{3k}&\sum_{y=0}^{x}(-1)^x\binom{n}{3k-x}\binom{n}{y}\binom{y}{x-y}\\
> &=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}(-1)^x\binom{n}{3k-x}\binom{n}{y}\binom{y}{x-y}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}(-1)^x
> \mathop{res}_u\frac{(1+u)^n}{u^{3k-x+1}}
> \mathop{res}_v\frac{(1+v)^n}{v^{y+1}}
> \mathop{res}_z\frac{(1+z)^y}{z^{x-y+1}}\tag{4}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u,z}\frac{(1+u)^n}{u^{3k+1}}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(-u)^x\frac{1}{z^{x+1}}
> \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\left(z(1+z)\right)^y\mathop{res}_v\frac{(1+v)^n}{v^{y+1}}\tag{5}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u,z}\frac{(1+u)^n}{u^{3k+1}}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(-u)^x\frac{1}{z^{x+1}}\left(1+z(1+z)\right)^n\tag{6}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^n}{u^{3k+1}}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(-u)^x\mathop{res}_z\frac{\left(1+z(1+z)\right)^n}{z^{x+1}}\tag{7}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^n}{u^{3k+1}}(1-u(1-u))^n\tag{8}\\
> &=\mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u^3)^n}{u^{3k+1}}\tag{9}\\
> &=[u^{3k}](1+u^3)^n\tag{10}\\
> &=\binom{n}{k}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we change the limit to $\infty$ without changing the value, since we add only $0$.
- In (4) we use $(1+u)^n$ as *formal power series* with the coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ according to (1) and do the same for each other binomial coefficient
- In (5) we do some rearrangements to prepare the application of the *substitution rule* for the innermost sum
- In (6) we apply the substitution rule according to (2)
- In (7) we do some rearrangements to prepare the application of the *substitution rule* for the other sum
- In (8) we apply a second time the substitution rule according to (2)
- In (9) we simplify the expression
- In (10) we use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[z^{3k}]$ to denote the coefficient $a_{3k}$ in $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$. Observe that following is valid when using the *formal residual operator* $\mathop{res}$

$$\mathop{res}_z\frac{A(z)}{z^{3k+1}}=[z^{-1}]z^{-3k-1}A(z)=[z^{3k}]A(z)$$

Comment: (+1) Very nice. Good to have this reference which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks, you're welcome! Maybe you'd like to review this [bounty question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917115/identity-with-catalan-numbers)? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start by restating the problem with a different choice of variables:
we seek to show that
$${n\choose k}
= \sum_{p=0}^{3k} {n\choose 3k-p} (-1)^p
\sum_{q=0}^p {n\choose q} {q\choose p-q}.$$

Re-write the sum as
$$\sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q}
\sum_{p\ge q} {n\choose 3k-p} (-1)^p {q\choose p-q}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${n\choose 3k-p}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k-p+1}} \; dz$$

This yields for the inner sum that
$$\sum_{p\ge q} {n\choose 3k-p} (-1)^p {q\choose p-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k+1}}
\sum_{p\ge q} {q\choose p-q} (-1)^p z^p \; dz.$$

The sum remaining in the integral is
$$\sum_{p\ge q} {q\choose p-q} (-1)^p z^p
= \sum_{p\ge 0} {q\choose p} (-1)^{p+q} z^{p+q}
\\ = (-1)^q z^q \sum_{p\ge 0} {q\choose p} (-1)^p z^q
= (-1)^q z^q (1-z)^q.$$

This yields for the inner sum the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k+1}}
(-1)^q z^q (1-z)^q \; dz.$$

To  conclude  substitute this  into  the outer  sum  that  we seek  to
evaluate to get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k+1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q}(-1)^q z^q (1-z)^q \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k+1}}
(1-z(1-z))^n\; dz.$$

Note that $(1+z)\times (1-z\times (1-z)) = 1 + z^3$ so this becomes
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z^3)^n}{z^{3k+1}} \; dz$$

To conclude observe that
$$[z^{3k}] (1+z^3)^n = {n\choose k}.$$

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).