# notation for first and second derivatives of a power series

Tags: derivatives, notation, power-series

I have a power series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_k}{k!}x^k$$
where $c_k$ is an arbitrary $k$-th term of some sequence.  Then
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_k}{k!}x^k\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-1}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}$$
Now, is it okay to leave this like this?  I know that the first two terms are  $0$, which removes the $1/x^2 $ term when $k=0$ and $1/x$ term when $k=1$.  I figure this is no problem, but perhaps I am wrong.  Should I re-index or can I leave it like this?

EDIT:  One of the reasons I'm posting this is I have an expression with a polynomial in front of the power series.  For example, 
$$(x-x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-1}$$ 
In this example, I have not re-indexed as has been mentioned in the previous posts and comments.  Now, since I haven't re-indexed, and if I distribute I get
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k+1}$$
Now, given that there is a polynomial coefficient in front of the derivative of a power series, can I NOT re-index and distribute first?

Comment: yes, you have to reindex to make it correct.

Comment: In the second sum, you should have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty$ and in the third, $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should keep in mind the following:

> If there is a *valid expression* then
>
> - *re-indexing* by adding one or more zeros or skipping one or more zeros does *not alter the value* of the expression
> - *index shifting* does *not alter the value* of the expression

Therefore we conclude:

> - **Re-indexing** and **index shifting** of an expression are only referring to **presentational aspects** and so they are always only a **matter of convenience**.

So, it belongs only to *your valuation* if re-indexing or index-shifting is convenient. But as you already know, a *proper presentation* is often beneficial since it can be used to

> - simplify the expression
> - clarify aspects you want to indicate
> - make further transformations of the expression easier (or possible :-))
> - etc.

So, let's have a look at your first question:

> Is it ok to leave the power series like this?
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2} \tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The answer is: *Of course it's ok*, since nothing is wrong with it.

BUT, presumably the *presentation* is not convenient because as you correctly noted, the first two summands are
\begin{align*}
\frac{0\cdot(-1)\cdot c_0}{0!}x^{-2}=0&\qquad\qquad(k=0)\\
\frac{1\cdot0\cdot c_1}{1!}x^{-1}=0&\qquad\qquad(k=1)\\
\end{align*}
Therefore we could *simplify* the expression (1) by re-indexing, index shifting and cancelling and also indicate thereby which summands are *more interesting*

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{c_k}{(k-2)!}x^{k-2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_{k+2}}{k!}x^{k}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Observe, that the presentation (2) represents *exactly the same* value as (1) and so they are completely interchangeable.

Now let's go on with your other question regarding:

> Can you distribute without re-indexing the following:
>   \begin{align*}
> (x-x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-1}=
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k+1}
> \end{align*}
>   The answer is again: Of course you can, since multiplication with $x$ and $x^2$ as well as applying the distributive law are valid transformations regarding this expression.
>
> Any re-indexing or index-shifting first or second, yes or no simply don't matter, since this is only a presentional issue and belongs exclusively to your convenience.

---

> *(Important) Note:* While re-indexing and index-shifting is harmless, we should be careful when **cancellation** comes into play. Observe:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2} \neq  \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_k}{(k-2)!}x^{k-2}\tag{3}\\
> \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{c_k}{(k-2)!}x^{k-2}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   Do you see the crucial difference? While cancellation in (4) causes no problems, since $\frac{k(k-1)}{k!}=\frac{1}{(k-2)!}$ is well defined for $k\geq 2$, the cancellation of the first two summands with $k=0$ and $k=1$ in (3) is *not valid*! The cancellation transforms these summands into

\begin{align*}
\frac{0\cdot(-1)\cdot c_0}{0!}x^{-2}=0&\qquad\longrightarrow\qquad\frac{c_0}{(-2)!}x^{-2}&\qquad(k=0)\\
\frac{1\cdot0\cdot c_1}{1!}x^{-1}=0&\qquad\longrightarrow\qquad\frac{c_1}{(-1)!}x^{-2}&\qquad(k=1)\\
\end{align*}

> The crucial fact here is, that cancellation removes the factor $0$ leaving an *invalid expression*. Using these invalid summmands erroneously in further calculations may lead to strange results!

---

> *(Harmless) Note:* You may expect that we always *skip* zeros in power series in order to simplify sums. This is not the case. Sometimes it's in fact convenient to *add* zeros to gain a better presentation. As an example you may have a look at my answer to [this question; see number (3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944035/binomial-theorem-generating-function/945958#945958).

Answer (score 3):

It is

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{c_k}{k!}x^k\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-1}\right]=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}.$$

Note that

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[c_0+c_1x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{c_k}{k!}x^k\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[c_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-1}\right]=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k-1)\cdot c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}.$$

So, you must reindex in your solution.

Comment: okay, so then $\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{k(k-1)c_k}{k!}x^{k-2}}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{c_k}{(k-2)!}x^{k-2}}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{c_{k+2}}{k!}x^k}$?

Comment: Your last expression should be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_{k+2}}{k!}x^k.$